# How to preserve initial state in React Component?

Tags: reactjs

I ran into a use case where I have to reset the current state to initial state. I tried preserving in an instance variable but forgot that it works through reference and when the state updates the instance variable will also update. When the user hits reset button the state should refer to initial state which is stored in `this.reset`. But I couldn't find a workaround.

```
class MyApp extends {Component} {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: null
    }
    this.reset = null;
    this.resetData = this.resetData.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const {data} = nextProps;
    this.reset = data;
    this.setState({
      data
    });
  }

  resetData(){
    this.setState({
      data: this.reset
    });
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <button onClick={this.resetData}> {this.state.data}</button>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: try `this.reset = data.slice()`. I think `this.reset` and `data` are pointing to the same array reference, hence why it's not setting the data to the original array

Comment: @mhodges that didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you able to use a third party library?

Lodash provides the [`deepClone()` method](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#cloneDeep) that would be useful to you for this, and would allow you to reset your component's state, regardless of the shape of `data` that is passed in.

You'll also want to make sure you use `deepClone()` each time you invoke `resetData()` to ensure that the `data` reference passed to `.setState()` is to a copy (clone) of your `this.reset` data, rather than a direct reference to the `this.reset` data:

```
import _ from 'loadash'

class MyApp extends Component {

...

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const {data} = nextProps;

    // Invoke cloneDeep to get a clone of data that is also a unique 
    // reference
    this.reset = _.cloneDeep(data); 

    this.setState({
      data
    });
  }

  resetData(){

    // Remember to clone reset data each time you reset data, so that 
    // data is a reference to a new copy of this.reset, rather than 
    // the reset data you stored when componentWillReceiveProps was 
    // called
    this.setState({
      data: _.cloneDeep(this.reset) 
    });
  }
...

}
```

Comment: awesome! thanks. I have to go through lodash even deeper than I thought.

Comment: you're welcome - yes lodash has some hidden gems :-)